# How to extract information from Dynamic Domain with PHP

Tags: php

Hello I'm trying to get this information from an HTML page but it doesn't have element,class, nothing it just have `<pre>all content</pre>` how can I extract the value from "validTo"? Information below
It is not a JSON FILE, its just the content of the web page.

```
[serialNumber] => 984924526890779987

[validFrom] => 180515204024Z

[validTo] => 180807195300Z

[validFrom_time_t] => 1526416824
```

PHP Code:

```
    <?php
    $url = "https://www.google.es";
    $orignal_parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $get = stream_context_create(array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => TRUE)));
    $read = stream_socket_client("ssl://".$orignal_parse.":443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
    $cert = stream_context_get_params($read);
    $certinfo = openssl_x509_parse($cert['options']['ssl']['peer_certificate']);
echo $certinfo
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you load the actual page into DOMDocument?

Comment: Updated with PHP Code tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work **if the page is formatted the way you described**.

```
// get the webpage - replace your.url with the actual webpage address
$html = file('your.url',FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) ;

// get your value 
foreach($html as $line) {
    $result = strpos($line,'[validTo]') ;
    if (false !== $result) {
        $temp = explode('=>', $line) ;
        $validTo = trim($temp[1]) ;
        break ;
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked, thanks you but the break its not necessary right? :P

Comment: @Joanmi, the `break` stops reading the rest of the html. It is more efficient and it is the proper way to exit the search for your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your file has this content

> file.html

```
[serialNumber] => 984924526890779987
[validFrom] => 180515204024Z
[validTo] => 180807195300Z
[validFrom_time_t] => 1526416824
```

Now this will extract the info and put it into an array named `$arr`. Access each by using that array.

```
<?php 
    $data = file_get_contents('http://domain/file.html');

    $arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);

    echo $arr[0];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can extract more info from a string by using Regex.

```
<?php
$string = "
<pre>
    [serialNumber] => 984924526890779987

    [validFrom] => 180515204024Z

    [validTo] => 180807195300Z

    [validFrom_time_t] => 1526416824
</pre>
";

preg_match('/\[validTo\].[\=\>].*[0-9a-zA-Z]/', $string, $values, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($values);
```

The Result was:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [validTo] => 180807195300Z
            [1] => 97
        )
)
```